# What method of encryption is suitable for encrypting individual words, and also an entire document?

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, cryptoapi, encryption-symmetric

I need to save several documents to the cloud and need to save the documents, document metadata, and words/phrases for searching.

My plan is to use a symmetric cypher for encrypting the whole document, but I'm unsure of the right way to hash each word.  I would like something secure, but I don't want to increase the count of characters in each word unnecessarily.

What implementation is most suitable for doing a symmetric encryption against a document, and what is the best way to hash a word or phrase without making it many times larger than it needs to be?

Comment: The problem with encrypting single words is that you will have to store the *key* securely, and that will be roughly as hard as storing the *word* securely...

Comment: If the key never gets uploaded to the server and is always on my site then how is that private key unsecure?

Comment: What threat are you defending against? Encryption is possibly not event the right tool to solve your problem, and certainly the system you are describing is a bad idea from a cryptanalysis point of view. What's the resource, who is attacking it, and why do you beleive that encryption helps?

Comment: @Eric Lippert I want to outsource a large Lucene/Solr index containing business documents to the cloud.  The data may be maintained by a 3rd party who implements this on Azure.  Both MSFT and the implementor would have a contractual obligation to secrecy, but I want to remove temptation wherever possible.  This is a theoretical idea that was inspired by [this Azure library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AzureDirectory).  I haven't formalized a threat model but am very open to direction and feedback.

Comment: My understanding is that BPOS Archive (a 3rd party product) operates in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest different tags.  It sounds like you're really interested in offloading searching to a server in a cryptographically secure way (such that the server doesn't have access to the plaintext and such that the client need not transfer the entire index).

Issues:

- An attacker being able to figure out which words are in the index (and which are not) could be an issue for you.  You should state whether it is as a part of your requirements.
- An attacker being able to figure out which items in the index occur more frequently could be an issue for you.  You should state whether it is as a part of your requirements.
- An attacker being able to associate words with a document could be an issue for you.  You should state whether it is as a part of your requirements.
- An attacker may be able to subvert the server entirely and observe queries / retrievals.  You should state security needs in this circumstance as well.
- Probably others I haven't thought of.

I'm assuming that you're designing your own, but there is probably some prior art, research, etc. that would be smarter than I am below:

For the first, I suggest that you should hash the words, combining the plaintext with a secret (not shared with the index server) before hashing, and truncating the hash to the point where it is likely to be non-unique in the index.  This costs you hash efficiency, but helps prevent an attacker from using the hash as a plaintext equivalent or experimentally determining the secret

For the second and third, you should encrypt any indexed data (such as counts or document+position) and decrypt it on the client.  This may cost you latency.

For the fourth, you'd want to consider concealing real requests inside groups of unrelated requests, things like that, but you'd want a lot of math to make sure you weren't still vulnerable to statistical analysis.

For the fifth, do some web research.  I'm confident there will be stuff out there, and this is a pretty specific (and less common) need, so you'll want someone who put more thought into it than I just have.

Comment: +1 This is a very smart and helpful reply.  I will continue to look for prior art and anything that will help with the design

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are mutually exclusive.  That kind of metadata will leak a huge amount of information about the document content, to the point it can't be called secure.

Furthermore, encrypting individual words is futile.  The difficulty of breaking encryption is usually said to be as difficult as breaking the key, but this assumes the information content in the plaintext is greater than that in the key.  For single words, that certainly isn't true.

Comment: The reason I thought of encrypting words is to facilitate the searching of an encrypted document, saved at a 3rd party location.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: @makerofthings: Store the entire search index database file(s) and encrypt them all together.  Every time a document is added, the creator has to also update the index, re-encrypt it, and upload the index.  This probably only is worthwhile if the expected read/write ratio is high.  What you definitely don't want to do is combine multiple accounts documents into a single index, since any user can find out a lot of information about any document listed in their index, even if they don't have the ability to decrypt the document itself.

Comment: If reuploading a comprehensive index is too expensive, you can split the index into two -- one with is updated infrequently and contains all documents which existed at that time, and one really small one which contains newly added documents.  Every search gets run twice, once against each of the two indexes.  Periodically you merge the index of new files into the big index, and reset the index of new documents..  That way the big index isn't transferred very often.

Comment: So if I were to put this in the context of Lucene, how would searching be done?  The encrypted index would be downloaded, decrypted, and searched?  What if I want to find all documents with the word 'AIG' or 'insider trading'... do I need to download every single index and go through that process?  Kinda kills the point of what I'm trying to achieve: secure search efficiency

Comment: @makerofthings: You'd have one index for every document collection you have access to (2 if using the cumulative/new split described above).  You'd probably have to redownload/redecrypt the new indexes fairly often, but the cumulative ones would only change maybe once per month.  To a large degree, confidentiality and search efficiency are mutually exclusive.  If you put everything into a single index, everyone will know you have a document that matches their search, even though they don't know exactly what that document contains.  With multiple searches, they might get the entire content.

Comment: Assume every word/phrase has a corresponding field.  This field is the result of a salted/encrypted ID of the file.  This field can only be decrypted on the client. This link decouples the word/phrase from the document.  This should alleviate your concern, and satisfy my requirements.

Comment: .. so back to my question.  How should I hash the word?